# Email validation with spaces in Front and back of names or emails

Tags: validation, email

When validating an email or names, would services usually consider the usage of spaces at the front or back of emails?

For example:
A valid email would be

```
Sample@email.com
```

But would an input of

```
[space]Sample@email.com
```

or

```
Sample@email.com [space]
```

be the same as Sample@email.com when entered?

Answer (score 1):

This regex will help you to validate email and no space before and after email

```
/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

Try this out!